# What do you call the roads along the coast or borders of a country?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

In Portuguese we call it *marginal* (which I would say relates to the word margin, i.e at the border of something).

No result from Google Translate felt as the right answer.

We may say for example *Vou pela marginal* which means *I'm going to take the __ road*.

**edit**
My bad, I posed the question wrong I guess. I forgot to mention that what I had in mind was roads at the coast, I'm not sure every country has roads at their borders (probably not), but countries with beaches usually have roads for better access. So I meant, roads touching the ocean or something like that. Coastal road/highway would be it.

Comment: In the US the concept of "bypass" for a road passing around a town or other congested area is fairly common (and goes back 100 years or so).  We don't really have any countries that one could (physically, at least) "circumvent".

Comment: See my comment on accepted answer :P bad word choice, any suggestions for a better title? I was thinking of coast highways, that give access to beaches.

Comment: Doesn't the OP mean *circumnavigate*?

Comment: 6. Estrada ou rua junto à margem ou junto a uma grande extensão de água. in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/marginal [consultado em 20-07-2018]. That means coastal road but can also a road along a river or lake or the coast. The definition in Portuguese means: along a body of water.

Comment: In English, we say; roads along the coast. A margem de, or marginal means along or alongside in English. Coastal highways or coastal motorways.

Comment: Credo, você prefere sacrificar qualidade, né? A traducão de marginal nesse sentido é along ou alongside ou by. A margem do rio: along the river. Nada tem a ver com a palabra marginal em inglês.

Comment: And a road along a river is almost always called "River Road".

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, well, I mentioned that in my answer, but not as a proper name....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the   morphology   and the boundaries of the country.

***[Coastal](http://www.yourdictionary.com/coastal)  road/highway*** is an example of a road running along the border of a country partly surrounded by the sea.

A more generic expression  is ***border road!***

Comment: What about land locked countries, say?

Comment: My bad, I posed the question wrong I guess. I forgot to mention that what I had in mind was roads at the coast, I'm not sure every country has roads at their borders (probably not), but countries with beaches (where the sea is touching them) usually have roads for better access. So I ment, roads touching the ocean or something like that. Coastal road/highway would be it.

Comment: @RealAnyOne - I first thought about the cost because you talked about Portugal..which has bearthtaking coastal roads.

Comment: A coastal road does not mean at all "running along the border of a country". Border road is completely off. A border road would mean a road running along a border (of some kind).

Comment: @Lambie - have you ever been to Florida?

Comment: @user070221  The English is completely wrong in your description.  Your language probably contains: au bord de la mer, or al borde de and you mistakenly then say in English, along the border. I suggest your return to your dictionaries. Florida has no border roads; Florida has coastal highways! Countries have borders, yes. Few have border roads.

Comment: @Lambie - I wonder about your Dictionary, please read correctly. My suggestion is coastal road/highways. Border roads as a generic term, the expression does exits, sorry for your Dictionary: https://www.bbc.com/news/av/uk-northern-ireland-40933759/a-myriad-of-irish-border-roads

Comment: @user070221 Yes, a coastal road is right. But your answer is all screwy: "***an example of a road running along the border of a country partly surrounded by the sea.***" That is 100% off and 100% incorrect. And ***border road is not a more generic expression for that***. It is a mistake. You can run but you can't hide. Too many years in the saddle (clue: that's two idioms).

Comment: @user067531 The roads referred to in your link are not like the ones described by the OP. The OP describes roads running _along_ the coast or border, the 'border roads' in the article are ones which _cross_ the border. In the Irish situation there are ones which existed before partition, continued to be used post patition, were a problem during the Troubles, stopped being a problem after the Good Friday agreement as there was then freedom of movement between two EU states but will become problematic should the UK leave without a well-defined deal. Sorry, I nearly used the B-word.

Answer (score 1):

6. Estrada ou rua junto à margem ou junto a uma grande extensão de água. in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/marginal [consultado em 20-07-2018].

   Priberam is an excellent Portuguese dictionary.

Translation of the definition: A highway or road alongside or to the side of a large body of water.

So, roads run along rivers, coastlines or lakes.

That would give us: coastal road, riverine road (technical), road along a river or river road or riverside road (non-technical) and lakeside road or road along a lake.

In Portugal, the highway (BrE: motorway) that runs along the coast, is said to be a marginal, but not all marginals need run along the seacoast.

Example: [Cascais coastal road](http://www.cmjornal.pt/portugal/detalhe/transito--marginal-de-cascais-cortada-devido-as-ondas)

The article says: Marginal de Cascais cortada devido às ondas Via está encerrada entre Caxias e Paço de Arcos.

Cascais Coastal Highway [or Road] Shut Off due to waves

Estrada marginal in the article is again: Coastal road. Because the road is "by the sea" (alongside), it is "uma estrada à margem do mar.

> coastal highway [American English]or coastal motorway [British
> English]

Comment: Can you edit to emphasize the final answer of **coastal highway/motorway**?

Answer (score 0):

In Ame usage:

a **beltway**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/beltway)

> A high-speed highway that encircles or skirts an urban area.

a **bypass**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bypass)

> A highway or section of a highway that passes around an obstructed or
>   congested area.

As America is composed of 50 states and only has 2 contiguous countries, these terms are used to circumvent said areas when traveling by car (not to be confused with detour, which is usually a temporary re-routing).

> A highway or section of a highway that passes around an obstructed or
>   congested area.

Comment: A beltway in Portuguese is a via periférica, not a via marginal.